# Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView

Tags: android, gradle, webview, android-webview

I'm facing an unusual issue where i'm not able to use webview anywhere in my app.
It is giving following exception.

```
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at com.mobile.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:26)
        at com.mobile.module.web_view.Hilt_FSWebViewActivity.onCreate(Hilt_FSWebViewActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:230)
        at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4536)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
2021-05-10 20:05:57.056 28318-28318/com.mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
            ... 30 more
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:225)
            ... 41 more
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package not found: com.android.chrome
        at android.webkit.WebViewDelegate.getPackageId(WebViewDelegate.java:164)
        at sX3.b(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-443009121:1)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFac`enter code here`toryProvider.e(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-443009121:35)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.<init>(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-443009121:12)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForO.<init>(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-443009121:1)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForO.create(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-443009121:1)
            ... 43 more
```

I created a different app with only one activity containing webview and it is working fine.

**Please help me in understanding what might be the issue.**

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 29

// Android Libraries
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3'


// Google Libraries
//implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

// Kotlin Libraries
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.21"

// Rx
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
//implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.3.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

// Image Processing
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0')/* {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}*/
//implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

// ROOM
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6'
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.6"

// Testing Libraries
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

//HILT - DI Dependencies
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01'
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

//Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"

//Data binding
annotationProcessor 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:4.1.3'

//Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

//Material Design Components
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

//Coroutines
def coroutines_version = "1.4.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

//Lifecycle LiveData
def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

implementation project(path: ':googlecloudtts')

// Dynamic Feature Module Support
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'

implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3'

implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'

implementation ('com.akexorcist:localization:1.2.9') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
}

implementation 'com.ramotion.directselect:direct-select:0.1.1'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

**Project level gradle:**
[image]

**Project has an other submodule which has a module level dependencies as below:**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20160810'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace, such as additional "Caused by" sections?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added full log. Thanks for response.

Comment: "I created a different app with only one activity containing webview and it is working fine" -- the crash seems to be coming from trying to use Chrome for the `WebView` implementation. But, if this is working in a separate project, that suggests that one of your dependencies from the real project is affecting how `WebView` resolves what implementation to use. Is Chrome available on this device for this user?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, chrome is installed on the device. Is there a way to find out conflicts in dependencies?.

Comment: If you are asking how to determine what dependency might be affecting `WebView`, I do not know. If you can reproduce the problem in the scrap project by adding all of the dependencies, you could do "debugging by binary search", removing half of those dependencies, seeing if the problem still occurs, and repeating that until you isolate the single dependency that is the source of the trouble.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did the exact same thing this morning. could not reproduce the issue in dummy project even after adding all the dependencies. I'm quiet confused on what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue with the code.

It was related to localization library **com.akexorcist:localization:1.2.9**

Please check the issues section in github:
https://github.com/akexorcist/Localization/issues/105

Issue is solved in **com.akexorcist:localization:1.2.10**

Comment: Its still there in 1.2.10

Comment: ..even in 1.2.11